# Can't establish a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and SQL Server 2000 for my vb.net desktop application..I'm having a SQL Server exception saying that

> "connection can't be established to the server.

When connecting to SQL Server 2005 this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. Also showing

> error 40-could not open a connection to SQL Server

Can I know the reason for this and the possible solution

Comment: Is the database on your local machine or a remote one? Can you connect to the database using Management Studio?

Comment: Database is on my local machine...Don't have management studio rather enterprise manager (have sql server 2000 installed).....Actually i don't know why the problem is arising just when i change my Monitor, LCD screen...my system is same but running with different monitor it shows this error and when i run with monitor using which i have developed the application it runs successfully....Looks silly but it's happening

Comment: using enterprise manager i can run query successfully with either of the display screens that means i can connect to the database...

Comment: a monitor has nothing to do with a connection to sql server.

Comment: Is your Visual Studio 2005/SQL Server 2000 environment running on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a video to demonstrate changing the monitor causing the error and changing it back resolving the error because I dont think anyone believes you.

My advice is to check the FireWall, see here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/09/sql-server-fix-error-1326-cannot-connect-to-database-server-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

I'd try turning it off your firewall as @JeremyThompson suggests. If that works setting an exception in the firewall (port is *I think* 1433) should allow you to connect.

If not, check the connection string you're using to talk to your database, there's a [useful reference here](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server). Let us know how you get on.

Comment: When i plugged out the internet cable then it couldn't establish a connection but when the cable was plugged in the NIC then it connected

Comment: Here is the connection string "Data Source=TAHA;Initial Catalog=ADT;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Try 

    "Data Source=TAHA;Initial Catalog=ADT;Integrated Security=SSPI;"